# Include images in Aggregator feed

Tags: 7, feeds

Drupal 7.  I'm bringing in an RSS feed, and for the most part it's working.  It's not, however, bringing in the images with each entry.  I tried adding an  to the list of allowed tags in the admin screen, to no avail.  The lines come across as this:

```
<media:thumbnail url="http://www.bjtonline.com/uploads/tx_bjt/FINAL3_Flexjet_thumb_b.jpg"/>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That is the correct way (AFAIK) for embedding a thumbnail into an RSS feed. What result are you seeing and what result would you expect?

Comment: The aggregator is simply bringing in the title - which is linked, correctly, to the articles' URL.

I wanted to know how we can modify the module to we can also bring in the image.

Comment: Any ideas?  I see where the module is bringing the data in, I guess I can customize it there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've not gotten anywhere with this, I'm working around it.  I'm only interested in bringing in the most recent article from a site that's on our own servers - so I'm writing a script that will import it into the node table and I'll use Views for the block.

I'll set the script to run nightly. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: instead of this you should show up your script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Feeds: MediaRSS](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_mediarss) module to fetch `media:thumbnail` type of data.

This is from the projects page, currently only supports following media types.

> media:content - WORKING
>
> media:title - WORKING
>
> media:description- WORKING
>
> media:keywords (csv)- WORKING
>
> media:thumbnail (url) - WORKING
>
> media:categories (csv)- WORKING
>
> media:player (url) - WORKING

For further reading on media rss:
http://www.rssboard.org/media-rss